# Get text listview with multiple textview android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have a `ListView` with two `TextView` and I need to get value of a `TextVeiw` but get me wrong data .

For example get me duplicate data.

```
lstContent.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

        //String selectedFromList =  (lstContent.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString()); 
        //String selectedFromList = lstContent.getSelectedItem().toString();
        //String txtselect = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        //select = txtselect.getText().toString();
        //Log.i("Log_five", select);
        //Log.i("Log_five", selectedFromList);
    }
});
```

I use above comment codes but all of them get me wrong data .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
lstContent.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

        TextView txtView1 = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);  //first TextView
        String text1 = txtView1.getText().toString();
        TextView txtView2 = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.txtView2);  //second TextView
        String text2 = txtView2.getText().toString();
        Log.i("Log_five", text1);
        Log.i("Log_five", text2);
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int postion, long id) {
    String contactId = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cid)).getText().toString();
```